# Pycharm debug window console: ENTER starts new line

Tags: pycharm, console, ipython

[image]

[image]

If I press enter at the end, it won't execute the command, just start a new line basically.
In the past Enter executed the command, have no idea why now like this.
**Any idea why this is, or how to change it back?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried resetting keymap, not enough.
My debug window was floating on separate window, had to go on
top right corner >> Restore Default Layout
Once again in Pycharm main window, Enter executes the line.
[image]